# Inner join rows not affected

Tags: mysql

When i try to insert data in my table salesfacts using this codes, it says that 0 rows are affected, but when i remove the insert, only executing the select, it shows my salesfacts table. Anyone can help me solve this problem please.

```
truncate table SalesFacts

INSERT INTO Assignment1SS..SalesFacts
(ProductCode, CustomerNumber, EmployeeNumber, officeCode, buyPrice, MSRP, quantityOrdered) 

SELECT 

p.ProductCode, 
c.CustomerNumber, 
e.EmployeeNumber, 
y.officeCode, 
p.buyPrice, 
p.MSRP, 
od.quantityOrdered

FROM
Assignemnt1..[OrderDetails] od INNER JOIN Assignemnt1..[Orders] o
ON od.orderNumber = o.orderNumber

INNER JOIN Assignment1SS..[ProductSS] p 
ON od.productCode = p.productCode

INNER JOIN Assignment1SS..[CustomersSS] c
ON od.OrderNumber = c.CustomerNumber

INNER JOIN Assignment1SS..[EmployeeSS] e
ON c.SalesRepEmployeeNumber = e.EmployeeNumber

INNER JOIN

(select e.[EmployeeNumber], y.[officeCode]
from Assignemnt1..[Employees] e
inner join Assignemnt1..[Offices] y
on e.officeCode = y.officeCode
group by e.[EmployeeNumber],y.[officeCode]) y

on c.salesRepEmployeeNumber = y.EmployeeNumber
```

**CustomersSS table**

```
    Create Table CustomersSS (
CustomerNumber int NOT NULL,
CustomerName varchar (50) NOT NULL,
ContactLastName varchar (50) NOT NULL,
ContactFirstName varchar (50) NOT NULL,
Phone varchar (50) NOT NULL,
AddressLine1 varchar (50) NOT NULL,
AddressLine2 varchar (50) NULL,
City varchar (50) NOT NULL,
State varchar (50) NULL,
PostalCode varchar (15) NULL,
Country varchar (50) NOT NULL,
SalesRepEmployeeNumber int NULL,
CreditLimit money NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (CustomerNumber));
```

Comment: And selecting * from the table afterwards confirms 0 rows? Or is data inserted?

Comment: after i tried to execute this whole list of data, it shows 0 rows, when i select the table, there's nothing inside too

Comment: Okay, so we note the value from insert was correct. But the select part with all joins and conditions does return data?

Comment: there's no data in the table, so it only returns the table with no data inside

Comment: Can you run the SELECT 

p.ProductCode, 
c.CustomerNumber, 
e.EmployeeNumber, 
y.officeCode, SQL with **all joins**?

Comment: If its not too complex.- maybe setup sqlfiddle?

Comment: yup, i can run that, it returns me the salesfacts table with all the columns inside

Comment: it requires 2 database so it might be too complex

Comment: Well - it doesn't return the salesfacts table - only the data you want right? Missing insert permissions?

Comment: yeah i want it to insert data into the table

Comment: Try an Insert into your table giving real values ( 1 dummy row) and check what That does

Comment: yup, it works, the row went in the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is wrong please use below query.

```
Your fault is 

    INNER JOIN Assignment1SS..[CustomersSS] c
    ON od.OrderNumber = c.CustomerNumber

Change query :

truncate table SalesFacts
INSERT INTO Assignment1SS..SalesFacts
(ProductCode, CustomerNumber, EmployeeNumber, officeCode, buyPrice, MSRP, quantityOrdered) 

SELECT 

p.ProductCode, 
c.CustomerNumber, 
e.EmployeeNumber, 
y.officeCode, 
p.buyPrice, 
p.MSRP, 
od.quantityOrdered FROM Assignemnt1..[OrderDetails] od 

INNER JOIN Assignemnt1..[Orders] o ON od.orderNumber = o.orderNumber
INNER JOIN Assignment1SS..[ProductSS] p ON od.productCode = p.productCode
INNER JOIN Assignment1SS..[CustomersSS] c ON od.CustomerNumber = c.CustomerNumber
INNER JOIN Assignment1SS..[EmployeeSS] e ON c.SalesRepEmployeeNumber = e.EmployeeNumber
INNER JOIN (select e.[EmployeeNumber], y.[officeCode]
                from Assignemnt1..[Employees] e
                inner join Assignemnt1..[Offices] y
                on e.officeCode = y.officeCode
                group by e.[EmployeeNumber],y.[officeCode]) y 
                    on c.salesRepEmployeeNumber = y.EmployeeNumber
```

Comment: Please provide CustomersSS table structure based on that check this line  on c.salesRepEmployeeNumber = y.EmployeeNumber.